# clang3.8 unmet dependecies on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, clang

I have for a while been trying to install Clang3.8 or for that matter any other version of clang. But every time I run into a problem with some unmet dependencies.

```
bonde@Bonde-Laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install clang-3.8
[sudo] password for bonde: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clang-3.8 : Depends: libclang1-3.8 (= 1:3.8~svn278388-1~exp1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libobjc-4.8-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: llvm-3.8-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried all the solutions that I have found all over the web, but none of them seem to work.

Hope you can help me or point me in the right direction. Maybe even explain to me what is going on, so that I in the future can fix it my self.

Comment: Your sources are messed up, probably.